# Show that $\frac{-1}{2}<\int_a^b\frac{x^3\cos {5x}}{2+x^2}<\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $f(x)\ge g(x)$ for every $x$ in $[a,b]$ and $f$ & $g$ are both bounded and Riemann integrable on [a,b]. At a point $c\in[a,b]$, let $f$ and $g$ be continuous and $f(c)>g(c)$ then prove that $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx>\int_a^b g(x) \ dx$ and hence show that $$\frac{-1}{2}<\int_a^b\frac{x^3\cos {5x}}{2+x^2}<\frac{1}{2}$$

**My work**

I have been able to prove the first part of the problem. My problem is to prove the inequality.

$$|f(x)|=|\frac{x^3\cos {5x}}{2+x^2}|\le |\frac{x^3}{2+x^2}|\le |\frac{x^3}{x^2}|=|x|$$ 
Taking this as $|x|=g(x)$

So now $$f(x)\le g(x)$$

Now $$\int_a^bg(x) \ dx=\int_a^b |x| \ dx=\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$$

According to the result obtained in first part,

$$|\int_a^b\frac{x^3\cos {5x}}{2+x^2}|\le\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$$

$$\implies\frac{a^2-b^2}{2}\int_a^b\frac{x^3\cos {5x}}{2+x^2}\le\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$$

So I would be able to prove the result if $a=0$ & $b=1$

But how can I prove it for any interval $(a,b)$?

Comment: It's not true for "any interval $(a, b)$." http://i.imgur.com/Kt1ZDSa.png

Comment: Wow! That was cool! How did you get the graph?

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. There could be a misprint in my book. I will get it cross checked.